# AngularJS closure memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks

As a relatively new person to AngularJS I would like to learn more about closures in AngularJS and how to use them to avoid leaking memory.

Am I right thinking that the below code leaks memory, as the references to func1, func2 and foo are not being released by the callback functions?

```
angular
  .module('Mod1').
  .controller('Ctrl1', ['$scope', 'foo', 'Service1', function($scope, foo, Service1) {

    var func1 = function() {
      // do stuff
    }

    $scope.func2 = function() {
      // do more stuff
    }

    Service1.loadData().then(function(data) {
      func1();
      $scope.func2();
      foo.func3();
    });

    $scope.$watch('blah', function() {
      func1();
      $scope.func2();
      foo.func3();
    });
}]);
```

Or will the callbacks be released on scope destroy automatically therefore removing last references to func1, func2 and foo?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript will cleanup the scope and the callback functions when the scope object is unreachable and no longer referenced by another object or function.

[Mark-and-sweep algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management)

> This algorithm reduces the definition of "an object is not needed
>   anymore" to "an object is unreachable".
>
> This algorithm assumes the knowledge of a set of objects called roots
>   (In JavaScript, the root is the global object). Periodically, the
>   garbage-collector will start from these roots, find all objects that
>   are referenced from these roots, then all objects referenced from
>   these, etc. Starting from the roots, the garbage collector will thus
>   find all reachable objects and collect all non-reachable objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
function assignHandler(){    
    var element = document.getElementById( "someElement" );
    var id = element.id;

    element.onclick = function(){
        alert(id);
    };
    element = null; 
}
```

Sample from [Professional JavaScript for Web Developers by Nicholas Zakas](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Professional_JavaScript_for_Web_Develope.html?id=KW9G9rdlStIC&source=kp_cover&redir_esc=y)

And, as i see, you're using AngularJS, so you should use `immediate invoked function` in this file(thats why all this function wouldnt be reached from global scope). Thats why, you would call function in `private scope` and it will lead to cleanup the scope, as was saying in previous answer.